# IPhone - Not able to enter text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone

We have a form which has a mandatory HTML text-area and a button which posts the form.

When user click the button with empty text-area, we show a popup that the text-area field is required and the popup has a close button on it, when a user clicks close button, we put the focus back on text-area. In this case, the keypad opens up in IPhone but the user is not able to enter anything in the field.
If the user click outside the text-area field and then again clicks on the field, then user is able to enter text in the field.
Same thing works in android device but not working for IPhone.

Can anybody give me a suggestion of what to look for or how to handle this?
We are using the `focus()` method to set the focus on text-area.

Comment: Please post some code, it will help others to answer your question better.